# How to setup Twitter and Facebook for MVC4 OAuth

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-oauth, facebook-oauth

I'm trying to use OAuth with an MVC4 application.  In AuthConfig there is a link ( http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=252166) but the information seems to be out of date.  It states to click the "Create an App" link but I don't see that link for Facebook or Twitter.  Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Facebook**
- Login to facebook
- Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps and you should see a button top right with "Create New App".

**Twitter**
- Login to Twitter
- Go to https://dev.twitter.com/apps click the Create new Application button

[image: Facebook]
[image: Twitter]